# Why do I keep getting errors while I try to login to my account with python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail

I was testing my account if my password can be cracked in Python 2.7. The code is like this.

```
import smtplib
passtext = open("dfg.txt", 'r')
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
for pw in passtext:
     try:
          s.login('sakibrezapathen@gmail.com', pw)
     except:
          s.login('sakibrezapathen@gmail.com', pw)
```

But I'm getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/spathen/PycharmProjects/untitled45/f.py", line 10, in <module>
    s.login('sakibrezapathen@gmail.com', pw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 622, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsS\n5.7.14 23IU7CEiTvSIkGrnjXINgL4GYR8kkuNuyNARebOpSPrDqyqpmfaYCHkf8jEeAmNMMYO4in\n5.7.14 QvVZz4lAOZGB2CP19BHYgH6QonH4bXBdA3OF-R3kFvBYb1xR5DYKuMXZPVDhMqj0tHK3sj\n5.7.14 DEqSRqlzmqXGpZ85LCSRgIpgZKxRWSe7uQZkvZ7Ra9GsUfkVa555PeTEUjwMbpf4u-ujc1\n5.7.14 2lKDggYyZL4FqoSGHo1fnI1-57wck> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q145sm16892586qke.37 - gsmtp')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: if `s.login('sakibrezapathen@gmail.com', pw)` throws, it will throw again in your `except` block...

Answer (score 1):

Visit the mentioned knowledgebase article: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754

There are two things you can do to enable access from the script:

1. Enable access for [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)
2. If that does not work, enable access from this [link](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)